# Why isn't $\mathbb{Z}$ an open set of the set of real numbers in the standard topology?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, integers

In class my professor said that the interior of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the empty set. That is because the interior is the union of all open sets contained in $A$. But why is it not an open set?

Can someone explain (without using metric definitions because we have not covered that)?

Comment: Without metric definitions, what is your definition of an *open set*?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z} = \left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n,n+1)\right)^c$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}$ is the complement of a union of open sets (intervals)

Comment: @juancodmw: does that address the question or the previous comment?

Comment: @robjohn The question

Comment: Sets are not doors! They can be simultaneously open and closed.

Comment: This doesn't occur here by connectedness. I'm sorry if my answer was rough.

Answer (score 1):

If you take an open interval centered around an integer $n$, it looks like $(n-\varepsilon, n + \varepsilon)$ for some real number $\varepsilon$. But $(n-\varepsilon, n + \varepsilon)$ will never be contained in $\mathbf{Z}$ for any $\varepsilon$; there will always be a non-integer real number in $(n-\varepsilon, n + \varepsilon)$. So $n$, which was arbitrarily chosen, cannot be in the interior of $\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: (+1) This is how I think about this, but the question is whether this qualifies as using the "metric definition".

Comment: Yeah I don't understand this as of now because my professor has chosen to save these sorts of definitions for later on in the course.

Comment: @MinuteCheesecake: you still haven't clarified in your question how you define an open set.

Comment: @MinuteCheesecake: if you are using $(a,b)$ as basis elements of your topology, then the topology whose basis elements are $(n-\varepsilon,n+\varepsilon)$ is exactly the same if you take $n=\frac{a+b}2$ and $\varepsilon=\frac{b-a}2$.

Comment: Do you really meant to say "there will always be a real number in $(n−\epsilon,n+\epsilon)$"?  Yes, for example $n$, but that's not a contradiction, since $n \in \Bbb Z$

Comment: @jjagmath Oh silly, but you know what I mean ;) In the future feel free to just edit away li'l errors like that

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean :)

Answer (score 0):

Standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is [generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) by the open intervals $(a, b)$ for $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore

$$
A = \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} (k, k+1)
$$

is an open set. However, $A$ is the complement of $\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed. Finally, the only [clopen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set) sets in the standard topology are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (a hallmark of a [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) space). Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}$ is not open.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that a base for the standard topology on $\mathbb R$ is the collection of all intervals of the form $(a,b): a<b$ then it's easy to show that $\mathbb Z$ is not open, for if so, then there would be a basis element $(a,b)$ of the aforementioned type such that $(a,b)\subseteq \{0\}$. Using the definition of open set, this would mean that there are $a<c<d<b$ such that $(c,d)\subseteq (a,b)$ and now $c=0=d$ which is impossible since $c<d.$

Comment: Now I am trying to read the proof of the theorem you linked. Anyway read my edit of the question.

Comment: So $M$ and $N$ are respectively a $m$ and $n$ manifolds in $\Bbb R^n$, right?